# Pandas Change To_SQL Column Mappings

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a slight problem in regards to `pd.to_sql()`. My task is to load excel files into a MSSQL database (import wizard is not an option). I've used `sqlalchemy` along with `pandas` in the past with success but can't seem to crack this.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

# Parameters for SQL
ServerName = "SERVER_NAME_HERE"
Database = "MY_NAME_HERE"
Driver = "driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0"

# Create the connection
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://' + ServerName + '/' + Database + "?" + Driver)

df1=read_excel('MY_PATH_HERE')
# do my manipulations below and make sure the dtypes are correct....

#... end my manipulations
df2.to_sql('Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

ERROR:
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native
Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Created On'. (207) 
(SQLExecDirectW)")
```

My issue is that the schema of the database is already set up and cannot change it. I have a column in my dataframe `Created On`, but the column name in the Database is `CreatedOn`. I have a handful of columns where this issue arises. Is there a way to set the mappings or schema correctly in [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)? there is a `schema` parameter in the documentation, but I can't find a valid example.

I could just change the column names of my dataframe to match the scehma, but my interest has been peeked otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following approach:

```
db_tab_cols = pd.read_sql("select * from [Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log] where 1=2", engine) \
                .columns.tolist()

df2.columns = db_tab_cols
df2.to_sql('Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

PS this solution assumes that `df2` has the same order of columns as `Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log` table

Comment: when I run `db_tab_cols` i get `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'.` it's failing on the `-` in `Auvi-Q`.. Special character `\\`` won't fix either. However if I just load the whole table `db_tab_cols = pd.read_sql("Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log", engine).columns.tolist()` it works? what gives? Second, they are not the same length `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 41 elements, new values have 45 elements`. Any ideas?

Comment: @MattR, what is the real table name in the SQL Server DB?

Comment: Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log. or to be more exact [dbo].[Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log]. EDIT: using the full name works... but still the length mismatch obviously :)

Comment: @MattR, you will have to make sure that `df2` has the same amount of columns as `[Auvi-Q_Evzio_Log]` table - obviously... ;)